# Unable to get Updates, E-Mail and Internet Access, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I am using a wireless connection.

The connection icon in the upper right hand corner of the screen indicates I am indeed connected, yet update manager, e-mail connections and internet access fail.

OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I am using my work computer to access this help site hoping some direction for these issues. I am new to Ubuntu and Linux as a whole. The last update indicated is July 30th.

That said, any suggestions for diagnostic steps or any other helpful directions would be appreciated.

`ping -c4 4.2.2.2` and `route | grep default` didn't return anything.

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:4d:50:b3:9e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1 
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B) 
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f0400000-f0420000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0 
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host 
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1 
          RX packets:3384 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:3384 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:187028 (187.0 KB)  TX bytes:187028 (187.0 KB) 

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:62:6d:23:d0:c0  
          inet addr:192.168.0.5  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0 
          inet6 addr: fe80::6e62:6dff:fe23:d0c0/64 Scope:Link 
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1 
          RX packets:32293 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2382888 (2.3 MB)  TX bytes:10990 (10.9 KB)
```

ip addr:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo 
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000 
    link/ether 00:22:4d:50:b3:9e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000 
    link/ether 6c:62:6d:23:d0:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
    inet 192.168.0.5/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0 
    inet6 fe80::6e62:6dff:fe23:d0c0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

iwconfig:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions. 

lo        no wireless extensions. 

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"CGnetwork"   
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: A0:21:B7:F7:EF:DB    
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm    
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off 
          Power Management:on 
          Link Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm   
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0 
          Tx excessive retries:13  Invalid misc:6   Missed beacon:0
```

ping and dconf read did not yield any results.

iptables -L:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns 
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm 
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn 
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds 
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps 
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc 
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST 

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] " 

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] " 

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] " 

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
ufw-user-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc 
ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900 
ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ufw-user-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] " 

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10 
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] " 

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL 
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST 
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST 
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] " 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination          

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references) 
target     prot opt source               destination
```

nm-tool:

```
NetworkManager Tool 

State: disconnected 

- Device: wlan0 ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Type:              802.11 WiFi 
  Driver:            rt2800usb 
  State:             disconnected 
  Default:           no 
  HW Address:        6C:62:6D:23:D0:C0 

  Capabilities: 

  Wireless Properties 
    WEP Encryption:  yes 
    WPA Encryption:  yes 
    WPA2 Encryption: yes 

  Wireless Access Points  


- Device: eth0 ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Type:              Wired 
  Driver:            e1000e 
  State:             unavailable 
  Default:           no 
  HW Address:        00:22:4D:50:B3:9E 

  Capabilities: 
    Carrier Detect:  yes 

  Wired Properties 
    Carrier:         off
```

Comment: I edited my initial query to reflect this information. Thanks.

Comment: @ Braiam: The internet works great in Windows 7; no issues, very fast. Please see question for iptables -L output. route|grep default did not create any output.

Comment: @Braiam: just added nm-tool output. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check if Network Manager is not managing your connection, click the network applet besides your user name and make sure "Enable Networking", "Wired" and "Wireless" are all active.

Also, seems that don't have a gateway set, it could be because your DHCP configuration is not being captured or that you have manually set your network configuration. If you set your network configuration **Manual**, you should verify that the gateway is filled out (**you don't have to use the same values as my screenshot, just see what values should be filled out in case you use the Manual method**):

[image]

If your method is **Automatic**, then try disabling your UFW.

Your UFW rules are dropping most of your packages, consider **allowing all output packages**, or at least packages which destination ports are desired, from your question you need to allow output to port TCP:80 (http) and input/output UDP:53 (DHCP). You can get a full port list in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). If you are not sure, just completely deactivate UFW rules, check if you have internet.

You can check what packages are being dropped doing a `dmesg | grep UFW` (it could be pretty long list).

Comment: Not sure what happened, but when I rebooted the wireless connection was recognized; internet and e-mail work as well! A million thanks Braiam!!